# TranslatablePage matching query does not exist wagtail custom menu issue

Tags: django, wagtail

when i am creating wagatil menu translatable page does not exist error display

{% load wagtailimages_tags cms_tags %}

{% get_menu "main" None request.user.is_authenticated as navigation %}

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-5">
        {% for item in navigation %}
            {% get_menu item.slug item.page request.user.is_authenticated as submenu %}
            <li class="{% if submenu %}dropdown {% endif %}p-2">
                <div class="dropdown show">
                    <a href="{{ item.url }}"
                            {% if submenu %} class="menuitem dropdown-toggle {% if item.icon %}menuicon{% endif %}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                            {% else %} data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ item.title }}" class="menuitem"
                            {% endif %}
                    >
                        {% if item.icon %}
                            {% image item.icon fill-30x30 class="image-menu" %}
                        {% else %}
                            {{ item.title }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
                    {% if submenu %}
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            {% for subitem in submenu %}
                                <a href="{{ subitem.url }}" class="dropdown-item menuitem p-2 {% if subitem.icon %}menuicon{% endif %}">
                                    {% if subitem.icon %}
                                        {% image subitem.icon fill-30x30 class="image-menu" %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        {{ subitem.title }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error message.

Comment: DoesNotExist at /en/
TranslatablePage matching query does not exist. this error display when i am adding {% get_menu "main" None request.user.is_authenticated as navigation %} on my mainmenu.html pls check the issue i am new in django wagatil